# How to login into domain when all local user account deleted?

Tags: windows-7, login

I've installed windows 7 via WDS. All drivers and some recommended softwares installed properly. I was deleted all local user accounts and I logged out. Then i was trying log into my domain like domain.com\user with password, it responsed : user name or password incorrect. 
I think it can't connect our domain. What should I do?

Comment: 1. Logging in to the domain is not dependent on the existence of local user accounts. 2. It's not possible to delete built-in user accounts so the Administrator account should still be available to you, although it's disabled by default, so that may present some challenges to you..

Comment: So is there any way to enable administrator account? When I login with Administrator, it responds like account disabled...

Comment: Try this: http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Comment: @joeqwerty thx man!

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I didn't used. I've used ERD

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some details with your question.

Did you join it to your domain / try re-joining it? Does the computer show up in ADUC? Are you 100% sure your domain password is correct?

Comment: Thank you for answering me!. It's for my bad. I was not added client to domain yet while I've deleted all local accounts. Is there any way to login to domain that computer not added in domain?

Comment: No there isn't.